# PowerShell: Set current item in foreach to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

thank you for looking. I want to loop through each item in a folder and add qualifying file names and lengths (sizes) to an array so I can send an email out. For example, if there are files without the .txt extension, I do not want to include them. What happens is the email is sent out, but lists the same files in several tables. I know if the issue is how I'm storing the current file to the array, but not sure how to fix it. I just want the current file in the foreach to be added once.

Here is my stripped out code:

```
$myFolder = "C:\Users\myName\Documents\Temporary"
$ReceivedCount = 0

$a = "<style>BODY{font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;}"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:    black;border-collapse: collapse; }"  
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 2px;padding: 7px;border-style: solid;border-color:    black;background-color:lightblue;padding-right: 2px;}" 
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 2px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color:     black;background-color:white; padding-right: 2px;}"
$a = $a + "</style>" 

foreach ($file in $myFolder)
{
    $FileName = $file.name

    Echo "Curent file: $FileName"

    if($FileName -like "*.txt")
    {
        $ReceivedCount += 1
        # This is the section I'm doing wrong:
        $FilesReceived += @(Select-Object name , length | ConvertTo-HTML -head        $a)
    }

}

Echo "Found $ReceivedCount files."

if ($FilesReceivedCount -gt 0)
{
    #send email...
}
```

Comment: Where do you clear `FilesReceived`? What object(s) is `Select-Object` operating on there?

Comment: I don't clear $FilesRecieved because once this script runs it is done. The Select-Object should only grab the name and length of the current file in the foreach loop.

Comment: So what multiple tables are you outputting here there isn't any looping (other than over files) here? Sample input and output might be helpful.

Comment: So for example, I have four files, taco.txt, nachos.txt, salsa.txt, and order.log. When I do the send-mailmessage, i want to email one table that lists each *.txt file's name and size.

What the code is doing now is it lists each of the three files in separate tables when I send the email out.

Comment: You are running `convertto-html` once for each file. If you want a single table I believe you need to run it once over the whole collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#$FilesReceived = @()
$FilesReceived += @($file | Select-Object name , length)

$html = $FilesReceived | Convertto-html -head $a
```

Btw you can filter the file selection beforehand if you use the `-include` parameter of gci like this:

```
Get-Childitem C:\path\*.* -Include *.txt
```

so you only handle .txt files

Comment: Okay, that definitely works, but when I send out the email each file is listed in a separate table. Any idea how to make them go to one table?

Comment: @AaronJohnsen I have edited the code. If you use the `$html` variable you should only have 1 table

Comment: Yes!! Just added -head $a after Convertto-html, and it is exactly what I needed, Thank you so much guys. You are awesome people.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to include the files in the table (and not use them later as in an array) you can just use:

```
$filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFolder "*.txt" | Select-Object Name | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

This will create a single table containing just the file names (add parameters to the select-object if you want othets). I use the pipe to select-object rather then -name flag on get-childitem as the flag will include the full path while select-object just includes name.